# What is the retry behaviour for the SQL Workflow Instance Store?

Tags: workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4, workflowservice

I'm having trouble finding any documentation on how the SqlWorkflowInstanceStore and how it handles retires.

In Workflow 3.x there was a property you could set called "EnableRetries" that allowed retries when the Persistence Store was unavailable, but I can't seem to see anything similar in Workflow 4.  Just to clarify, I know the "EnableRetries" is in .NET 4, but that's for legacy workflows.

I'm using Workflow Services not the Application or Invoker.

Can anyone shed any light?  Or point me in the right direction?

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you can't do this in Workflow 4.0

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [InstanceLockedExceptionAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/id-id/library/system.activities.durableinstancing.sqlworkflowinstancestore.instancelockedexceptionaction%28en-us%29.aspx). The exact timeouts are not configurable from what I've seen. In fact the best documentation I've seen on them is actually from the AppFabric documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677318.aspx).

Comment: Ok, I thought that only deal with situation where another host was trying to open an existing workflow.  Does that deal with possibility of the instance store disappearing for a few minutes and then coming back?

Comment: John, sorry, I misunderstood what you were looking for. As far as I know there are no properties to configure retires related to communicating with the actual SQL server in WF4. Strange they regressed from 3.5 in this respect.